# Javafx drag and drop to the finder

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

I have tried to implement a drag and drop function to the Finder/Windows Explorer. Whenever I call my function with more than one file on the dragboard java is crashing because OSX is showing me an exception that the quantity of the source and the quantity of the target are not the same. In javafx you cannot start drag and drop on a list of nodes, only on one node.

How can I archive this that I can drag and drop a list of nodes to the Finder without a crash ?
In other words how can I create a dragboard where the source is not a node, instat the source is a list of nodes ?

Here is my actual code:

```
imageGrid.setOnDragDetected((t) -> {
        /* drag was detected, start a drag-and-drop gesture*/
        Dragboard db = imageGrid.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);            
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Node> selection = factory.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        selection.forEach((k) -> {
            fileList.add(new File(((MediaGridCell) k).getItem().getName()));
        });
        content.putFiles(fileList);
        db.setContent(content);
        t.consume();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, however I'll give it a try anyway since you haven't get any feedback in several days.

When you use `ClipboardContent.putFiles()`, you are using:

```
DataFormat FILES = new DataFormat("application/x-java-file-list", "java.file-list");
```

Depending on the `Object` you are trying to put to the `ClipboardContent` you could use another `DataFormat`. Given that `ArrayList` class is serializable by default (not sure about `Node`) you could do:

```
final DataFormat dataFormat = new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");

public getClipboardContent(ArrayList<Serializable> list) {
    ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
    cc.put(dataFormat, list);
    return cc;
}

public List<File> getList(Dragboard db) {
    return db.getContent(dataFormat);
}
```

Comment: _not sure about Node_ ... how about consulting the api doc .. ;)

Comment: I think that is OP's job, isn't it? ;) And even if it's not serialized, you can serialize it.

Comment: the answer is in the responsibiliy of the answerer - an uncertainty that could be resolved by a quick lookup in the doc (and not done) makes it a smelly answer ..

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I want to drag a list of files to the native OS filemanager. 

What I have found out is that under windows and linux all is working fine because there is no check if the quantity of the source object and the quantity of the target object is the same exists. 

From the javafx API I have not found a way to specify a list of nodes as drag source and therefore I have now created a bug report for javafx on OSX.